# javamail BASE64DecoderStream decode issue

Tags: base64, jakarta-mail

Found an issue with Base64DecoderStream in javamail.  Some email content I get are like this:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=3D"utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

QmFzZTY0IGlzIGEgZ2VuZXJpYyB0ZXJtIGZvciBhIG51bWJlciBvZiBzaW1pbGFyIGVuY29kaW5=
    n
    IHNjaGVtZXMgdGhhdCBlbmNvZGUgYmluYXJ5IGRhdGEgYnkgdHJlYXRpbmcgaXQgbnVtZXJpY2F=
    s
    bHkgYW5kIHRyYW5zbGF0aW5nIGl0IGludG8gYSBiYXNlIDY0IHJlcHJlc2VudGF0aW9uLiBUaGU=
    g
    QmFzZTY0IHRlcm0gb3JpZ2luYXRlcyBmcm9tIGEgc3BlY2lmaWMgTUlNRSBjb250ZW50IHRyYW5=
    z
    ZmVyIGVuY29kaW5nLg==
```

Ideally the = sign should have been replaced with the single character on the following line but gsuite(Gmail) sometimes does like this.  This causes Base64DecoderStream to corrupt the message.  However, Outlook and many popular online base64 decoders handle this base64 content well.  Can this be fixed?

Comment: Yes, whatever mailer sent this broken message should absolutely be fixed.  Is it really Gmail that's sending messages like this?  Report it to Google immediately!  The JavaMail base64 decoder will ignore characters that are not valid base64 characters, but "=" *is* a valid base64 character with a well defined meaning.  This looks more like someone copied and pasted MIME content into a text message.  Can you send me an example of such a message at javamail_ww@oracle.com?

Comment: Thanks Bill for your response.  Yes, but not regular gmail, it is gsuite journaling email is doing this.  am sending you the email sample to javamail_ww@oracle.com

Comment: Tried sending the sample, i got this back: Final-Recipient: rfc822;<##maskedemailid##@oracle.com>
Diagnostic-Code: 550 Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable
Action: failed
Status: 5.0.0

Comment: Weird.  Can you try again please?

Comment: Same issue again, i did sent another email yesterday to this id querying about >2gb smtp support, that seems to have gone through..

Comment: One observation is that outlook opens the email without issues, also the online base64 decoders decodes this fragmented base64 without issues.

Comment: Actually, I got your messages, so I don’t know why you got an error.  I’ll look at them in more detail tomorrow.  Google really needs to fix this, and can probably fix it sooner than I can add a workaround to JavaMail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additional detail was provided privately, which allowed me to determine that the problem is that the message includes an attachment of MIME type message/rfc822 (the original message), and that attachment uses a Content-Transfer-Encoding of quoted-printable.  The MIME spec does not allow the use of that encoding for MIME content of that type.  This is a violation of the MIME spec that Google really needs to fix.  Please provide them this additional information if they haven't figured it out themselves.

RFC 2046, section 5.2.1, says:

> No encoding other than "7bit", "8bit", or "binary" is permitted for
>   the body of a "message/rfc822" entity.

In the mean time, you can set the JavaMail System property [`mail.mime.allowencodedmessages`](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/package-summary.html#mail.mime.allowencodedmessages) to "true" to work around this bug in GSuite.

Comment: Thanks Bill, mail.mime.allowencodedmessages property resolved the issue.  Also raised the issue with gsuite/gmail.